# "Pending approval" or "Approval pending"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm not a native english speaker so there are still some things that I don't fully understand.

What is the best way to say, in a software, that an item is waiting for the approval of someone? "Pending approval" or "Approval pending"?, Internet gave me ambiguous responses.

Waiting for your comments! thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both versions can be used.
**Pending approval** = the item is pending approval from someone;
**Approval pending** = the approval of the item is pending someone's action;

So you can use whichever version is more appropriate for you. I assume that **pending approval** might describe an earlier stage of actions, because someone who has to review the item might not yet have seen it. The second version could imply that the item is already in the approval process but the latter has not been finished yet.